# please help me understanding this wiring

Tags: wiring

[image]

From what I understand the black wire on the side is the Live wire. I was thinking that the other black wire would be the Load but I usually see them connected to the other side. The red probably is the traveller (this is not even a three way switch) but if that was the case wouldn't the other black wire be connected to the other wise as well?

Sorry if I am not making much sense. I switched a light switch last week where the bottom black one was a live wire and the top black was the load, was hoping to see the same inside this panel but the different wiring is throwing me off.

Comment: Does this switch perhaps control one or more outlets where one side of the outlet (top or bottom) is switched, but the other side is always on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two black wires that are effectively tied together through the lower screw and the push in connection on the back. It is likely that one is the hot feed to the switch and the other is an unswitched hot connection to some other circuit downstream, such as another switch, or an outlet.

The red wire is probably the switched hot going to the load.

If one of the black wires is hot to another circuit, there should also be white wires in the box connected to each other, probably at least 3 wires. One would come from the main panel, one to the load and one to the other circuit that shares the hot lead on the switch. There also may be more wires in the box unrelated to this circuit.

Comment: so pretty much someone decided to use the red wire as the load while the second black wire is the live wire going to another device. so i am going to disconnect the black in the back and tie it up (i dont think its going to any appliance, if something stops working I will connect it back) and then just use the red load and the black live for new switch. makes sense?

Comment: This is not set up as a three way switch. In a single pole switch, it is common to use black as the hot and red as the load, but that is not required or even standard. When properly set up, all hot leads, switched or not, will be marked as red or black, all neutral leads as white. This can be the color of the standard insulation, or it can be done with colored tape or a spot of paint.

Comment: Thanks bib. I was under the impression that in NA black is always used for live but I am familar that in other countries red is the standard for live. thanks again. gonna go try it out now.

Comment: @rm65453 bear in mind that the hot wire coming into the switch could be the one under the screw *or* the one in the push-in slot.  There's no standard suggesting it should be one or the other.  For that matter, while less likely, the red wire could be hot coming in and the two black wires could be feeding two loads, of the switch controls more than one thing.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I did test of the wire before proceeding ahead. pulled them all out, spread them apart and then tested each with a meter. the original answer was correct. thanks everyone

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot True, true. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question ... but some cleanup is needed as long as you have the switch out in the open.

1. Corrective Action Needed

[image]

Wires on screw terminals should never be installed like shown above. The terminating end of the wire should fit nicely under the screw. This installation as shown represents a total disregard for pride in craftsmanship not to mention the possibility that a wire installed like this may very well work loose more easily.

2. Another Corrective Action Needed

[image]

This shows another example of the shoddy workmanship. You should redo the wire as described above.

3. Missing Ground Connection

[image]

The switch bracket has no GND connection attached. This represents a safety hazard if the electrical box is a plastic one. This could be OK if the electrical box is metal, if the box itself is grounded and there is a special bracket to box contact clip at switch mounting screw.

4. Nasty Poke In Wire Connection

[image]

I have seen just too many poke in wire connections fail to not comment about this one. I think the right way to deal with this is that the two black wires, one at the screw and the other poked into the unreliable poke hole connection, should be joined with a third short black pigtail wire using a high quality twist on wire connector of the proper size. The pigtail wire should then be what attaches to the switch screw. Leave the poke holes empty.

Comment: I agree, was not too pleased with the quality of work upon opening the box. I have cleaned up all the connections and got rid of the extra black wire. The pigtail would have saved me all the confusion but I did not do that as the extra wire seems like a dead end connection to me, which again doesnt make much sense. maybe they changed their plans while wiring the house.